# i cant register a new application google+

Tags: google-signin

i need create an app to enable login with   google+ on my site (localhost), but y cant find steep 5 "In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps." the login button no show

1 Go to the Google Developers Console.
2 Select a project, or create a new one.
3 In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure the 4 Google+ API status is set to ON.
5 In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.
6 At the top of the page, select Register App.
7 Fill out the form and select Register.